# converting unquoted slash to newline without strtok or further memory allocation

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out why this doesn't work.

I'd like to take data from a file using the 'getline()' function and convert the string so that the slashes ('/') that are not in quotes are replaced with new line characters. I'd like to avoid copying the string to another if possible.

I tried my program below, with two attempts to process the same data. The first attempt wasn't quite right. I expected to see the following in both cases:

```
ABC
DEF'/'GH
```

But

```
printf("%s",newline);
```

only returns this:

```
ABC
DEF'/'
```

and:

```
printf("%s",newline2);
```

returns a segmentation fault.

Because the `getline()` function returns the string as a char array with memory pre-allocated to it, I feel a ridiculous solution would be:

```
  char lines[5000000];
  strcpy(lines,datafromgetline);
  char* newline=parsemulti(lines,10); //prints data almost correctly
  printf("%s",newline);
```

But could I somehow do this where I don't have to allocate local stack space or memory? Can I somehow modify the incoming data directly without a segmentation fault?

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

// replaces all occurrences of / not within single quotes with a new line character
char* parsemulti(char* input,int inputlen){
  char* fms=strchr(input,'/');
  char output[100000]; //allocate tons of space
  if (!fms){
    return input;
  }else{
    int exempt=0,sz=inputlen;
    char aline[5000];
    char*inputptr=input,*lineptr=aline;
    memset(aline,0,5000);
    while(--sz >= 0){
      if (*inputptr=='\''){exempt=1-exempt;} //toggle exempt when ' is found
      if (*inputptr=='/' && exempt==0){
    *lineptr='\0';
    strcat(output,aline);
    lineptr=aline;
    strcat(output,"\r\n");
      }else{
      *lineptr=*inputptr;lineptr++;
      }
      inputptr++;
    }
    if (exempt==1){printf("\nWARNING: Unclosed quotes\n");}
    *lineptr='\0';
    strcat(output,aline);
    strcat(output,"\r\n");
  }
  strcpy(input,output);
  return input;
}

int main(){
  char lines[5000];
  strcpy(lines,"ABC/DEF'/'GH");
  char* newline=parsemulti(lines,10); //prints data almost correctly
  printf("%s",newline);

  char* lines2="ABC/DEF'/'GH";
  char* newline2=parsemulti(lines2,10); //returns segmentation fault
  printf("%s",newline2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 2nd case, You can not change a string literal.

Comment: 1st case, `newline=parsemulti(lines,10);` --> `newline=parsemulti(lines,12);`

Comment: I just realized the 1st case 15 minutes after I posted the question. and for 2nd case, I guess the first parameter in the standard `getline()` statement is a string literal.

Comment: _getline() statement is a string literal._ I don't get you. Also `char lines[5000000];` is big in stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two lines

```
char lines[5000];
strcpy(lines, "ABC/DEF'/'GH");
```

will

- allocate memory for 5000 objects of type char on stack
- copy string literal contents to memory pointed by name "lines", which you can modify

on the other hand

```
char *lines2 = "ABC/DEF'/'GH";
```

defines pointer to string literal that is usually located in read only memory.
Read only, as in **do not modify me** :)

You tagged this **C** so I assume You are talking about using [getline()](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html) function - not a part of C standard, but provided by GNU C Library, that manages memory on it's own (so basically it can, and will do memory allocations, unless you preallocate it. It uses only heap memory, so if preallocated size is too small it reallocates it. Thus You can't provide address to stack char array instead).

To actually find and replace escape character from string, I'd say you should not reinvent wheel and use library string functions.

```
char *line = NULL;
char *needle;
ssize_t line_size;
size_t size = 0;

line_size = getline(&line, &size, stdin);
while (line_size != -1) {
  needle = strchr(line, '/');
  while (needle) {
      if (needle != line && !(*(needle - 1) == '\'' && *(needle + 1) == '\''))
        *needle = '\n';
      needle = strchr(needle + 1, '/');
  }
  printf("%s", line);
  line_size = getline(&line, &size, stdin);
}
```